# Get datetime from a table row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Let suppose that a row was inserted in a table with "id,name" fields (only), is it possible to get what date/time this record was inserted or updated using some mysql internal table or something like this? How? Thank you.

Comment: No, MySQL doesn't automatically record this. You need to add an explicit column for this. You can use `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to make it update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there's no timestamp metadata on individual rows.

You'll have to add a timestamp column yourself, defaulting to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

The closest thing you can get to what you're asking for is to comb through the binary log (if there is one), but this will have the commit time for the transaction, which may be different from the timestamp when the record was inserted.